# system() always returns non-zero when called as CGI

Tags: c++, linux, shell, cgi, system

When calling system() from cgi, it always returns -1 (meaning error). errno is set to 10, ECHILD.

The test.cgi containing:

```
cout << "/bin/true " << system("/bin/true") << endl;
cout << "/bin/false " << system("/bin/false") << endl;
cout << "/bin/touch /tmp/foo" << system("/bin/touch /tmp/foo") << endl;
```

called from command line, as ./test.cgi returns:

```
/bin/true 0
/bin/false 256
/bin/touch /tmp/foo 0
```

But calling this as a link from a web browser returns (after expectable malformed headers error message):

```
/bin/true -1
/bin/false -1
/bin/touch /tmp/foo -1
```

I have verified the commands are executed in both cases (file /tmp/foo is created), but calling them through httpd (mongoose, ARM9, Linux) returns -1.

Any hints, how to fix it?

Comment: there's no `cout << whatever` in C!

Comment: @eckes: Okay, keywords adjusted accordingly. I doubt think the choice of compiler: gcc or g++ is at fault here, but whatever...

Comment: guess it's a rights problem: does the user running the web server have the rights to execute `/bin/true` and `/bin/false`?

Comment: Do `/bin/sh` and `/bin/true` even exist in the web server's namespace? If it is `chroot`ed, perhaps not. How did you "verify the commands are executed"?

Comment: @Rob: they do. I'm launching a different command that beeps a little speaker the same way, and I can hear it beep. (and it returns the same -1 as opposed to actual return code when called from httpd.)

Comment: `man system` says: "The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g. fork(2)  failed),  and  the return  status  of the command otherwise." I wonder if the system administratively disables `system` or `fork` for CGI processes.

Comment: @eckes: yes, and other commands that can leave more tangible traces of being executed (say `echo $LD_LINUX_PATH >/root/ldpath` ) do leave them (and yes, the path is okay.)

Comment: @Rob: I'm pretty sure nobody disabled that consciously - this functionality worked fine before. The webserver got upgraded to newest version and recompiled with unicode support recently and... that's the result.

Comment: Ask the web administrator if the webserver runs with `chroot`. This is a security feature to prevent buggy CGI programs from turning into a way to hack the server.

Comment: @user315052: No, it does not. This is an embedded device, not only not enough room for chroot environment, if the attacker gains access to the WWW bypassing authentication, they have all functions of the device at hand.

Comment: Since you get `-1` return back, does `errno` provide any hints?

Comment: @user315052: ECHILD = 10 = No child processes. BUT the commands do get executed, I can run scripts, create files, manipulate outputs.

Comment: Please add `ECHILD` to your problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `system` call is failing because of an `ECHILD` error. This happens when `wait` is waiting, but there is no pending child. A possible cause for this is that your code (or some code you have called) has set a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`. To test for this, you can set the `SIGCHLD` signal handler to be `SIG_DFL`, to restore it to the default signal handler, just before your calls to `system`.

I don't want to get too far ahead of ourselves, so check to see if the above test works out. If it does, you can consider using the test as a fix if your program is single threaded, and you restore the signal handler to what it was set to after `system` completes. But, the actual fix would be to find out where and why the signal handler was set, and then make a judgement on what you want to do about it.

Comment: Yes, it works! `signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_DFL);` at the beginning causes correct results to be returned. Now I'd just wish who/where/why/what for breaks the handler...